# Leading zeros periods on JQuery Countdown Clock plugin

Tags: jquery

I'm using a JQuery [Countdown Clock plugin from here](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).

currently this is the image view

[image]

Unfortunately I need to have leading 0 where there are single digits. For example 3:0 should display as 03:00.

this is my current code

```
<p class="pull-right">
    Refreshing in: 
    <span id="countdown_hidden" style="display: none;"></span>
    <span id="countdown"></span>
</p>

<script>
    $('#countdown_hidden').countdown({until: 180, padZeroes: true,
        onTick: function(periods) {
            $('#countdown').text(periods[5] + ':' + periods[6]); 
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `function pad(n){return n<10?'0'+n:n}` -> `$('#countdown').text(pad(periods[5]) + ':' + pad(periods[6]));`

Comment: Read the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need a simple `pad2` function:

```
function pad2(n) {
    return ((n < 10) ? "0" : "") + n;
}
```

(the concatenation of the empty string in the >= 10 case ensures that the output is always a string)

Answer (score 0):

Use the compact mode of the countdown plugin (if the plugin is exactly this: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html )

```
 $('#countdown_hidden').countdown({
      until: 180, 
      padZeroes: true, 
      compact: true,
      format: 'MS' //minutes:seconds
 });
```

More info:

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html#quick (quick refference)